# Inception, 3 levels deep: multiple Youtube videos inside a Flexslider, inside a tab

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, youtube, flexslider

I am attempting to have multiple Youtube videos (in iframes) in a Flexslider inside an AJAX loaded tab (I like to make things complicated).  Each tab is a separate html file.  The Flexslider for the videos work when you first load the page, but if you are navigating between tabs, the arrow buttons no longer navigate between videos and I get the following error:  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopVideo' of undefined**

I think it is a problem with how the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function is indexing the videos and the stopVideo function (stops video playback if user hits the prev or next arrow) doesn't know what to call.  I've tried emptying the player array and calling this function manually, but it doesn't help.

If you'd like to see what it looks like currently, you can follow this link and click on tabs 7 and 8 as those are the ones with content currently:

http://desertsolchinooks.com/litter_fall2012_sungod8.html

I'm still quite a novice with all this and have learned so much from this forum already, but am hoping you guys can help out with this problem that has been a thorn in my side.  Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="flexslider">                  
              <ul class="slides">
                <li><iframe id="1" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ezHdquVu518?rel=0&loop=0&wmode=opaque" width="720px" height="405px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>  
                <li><iframe id="2" class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FzofvLLS92I?rel=0&loop=0&wmode=opaque" width="720px" height="405px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>                                        
              </ul>                                        
</div><!-- /flexslider -->

// ------ Youtube iframe API
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    $('iframe.youtube').each(function(i){
        var player = new YT.Player($(this).get()[0], {
            events: {
                //'onReady': myYT.onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': myYT.onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        // Reference each iframe and store the object for retrieval
        $(this).data('index', i);
        myYT.players.push(player);
    });
}

var myYT = {
    done: false,
    initFlag: true,
    init: function(){
        // Insert script on first run
        if (myYT.initFlag) {
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            myYT.initFlag = false;
        }
    },
    players: [],
    onPlayerStateChange: function(event) {
        function stopVideo(event){
            myYT.stopVideo(event.target);
        }
    },
    stopVideo: function(player) {
            if (typeof player.stopVideo === 'function') {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
    }
};

myYT.init();


// --------- Flexslider script
    $('#videoSlider .flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        selector: '.slides iframe',                                         
        slideshow: false,                   
        before: function(slider){

            // Stop all youtube videos in this slideshow
            // Use the 'index' data in each instance, to access object in myYT.players array
            slider.slides.filter('iframe.youtube').each(function(){
                myYT.stopVideo(myYT.players[$(this).data('index')]);
            });

            nextSlide = slider.slides.eq(slider.animatingTo)                    
        }   
    });
```